# Why is the performance of my HP laptop so poor even though a Lenovo with same specs performance better?

Tags: linux, laptop, linux-mint, hp-laptop

I recently purchased an HP, 15 ay516tx.

Its specs are 1TB 5400rpm HDD, 4GB 2133MHz DDR4 RAM, AMD RADEON 330M, even though these specs are more than required to run a linux distribution it underperforms very poorly.

After trying almost every popular distribution with different desktop environments I can conclude that this performance issue is with every linux distribution. I can see lags here and there, the cursor sometime does not move smoothly.

The opening and closing of apps is laggy.

After testing with Virtual Box I saw that whole 4gb of ram was being consumed but at normal operation almost 2GB remains free.

What is the problem? I am thinking of getting an SSD but I would like to not get one if I can increase the performance a little bit.

PS; BIOS version is F33, windows works great, and CPU governor is already set to performance mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to speed up your system is to increase the performance of the Block Device your OS and applications are installed on. Gaining lots of speed without changing the harddrive and a max of 4GB memory is unfortunately not possible. In ancient times we defragmented harddrives and got rid of unneccessary stuff so our files stayed on the inner side of the drive which made the access faster.

You have DDR4 RAM from 2015 but a 5400rpm Harddrive from the 1990's.

I guarantee, if you just change the harddrive, you will experience things you would not have expected.

Comment: To that I would add that 4GB - REALLY - is at the low end, get more if you can. Or rather: As much as you can, no reason to hold it back.

Comment: This is - depending on the usecase - not really neccessary because changing to SSD also improves the speed of "virtual" memory AKA pagefile or swap drive. in 2017 we have M2 drives which basically make the RAM requirement totally obsolete for certain usecases like browsing the web.

Comment: I'd agree that the usecase of web-browsning *might* fall into that category. Hint: browse on a site with the majority of the content being images.

Comment: *5400rpm Harddrive from the 1990's* Uh? In the 1990s they didn't make 1TB laptop drives (even now these aren't that frequent).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are referring to when you make the statement:

> ```
> windows works grea
> ```

If you tried linux and windows on the same laptop as a native deployment (i.e. bare metal install) and came to the conclusion that Windows is running more smoothly than linux, then it's likely a driver issue. The linux install is probably using an open source driver that doesn't support GPU acceleration, which are likely consuming CPU resources rather than the GPU's.  Change to the AMD proprietary drivers and compare the performance if you haven't already done so.  The lagginess you're experiencing is in-line with that conclusion.  Hard drive performance will not be drastically different between the two OSes; hence, if Windows runs great, then so should linux.  Regardless, you should upgrade your drive to an SSD if you can afford it because it's currently the bottleneck of your system.